# What does LE mean in the test-expression part of a for loop

Tags: coldfusion

Hi I'm very novice to coldfusion and I am trying to debug some cfscript logic. Basically I want to know what "le" means in the test-expression part of the for loop. I have looked through the coldfusion docs but can't find what it means. I am guessing it means less than or equals, but I believe that is denoted as LTE. Here's a sample of the code:

```
for (i = 1; i le length; i = i + 1)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Likely is a typo of "less than or equal to" (lte)

Comment: @vcsjones: Not a typo. You can use either `LE` or `LTE`.

Comment: LE is a legacy version of LTE from first versions of coldfusion.  It's ugly, eh?  :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is an [alternate way of saying LTE](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec09d55-7ffc.html). These are equivalent:

```
 LESS THAN OR EQUAL TO
 LTE
 LE
```

But for new code, I would use `<=` instead. It is more intuitive.

```
for (i = 1; i <= length; i++) {
   ... 
}
```